# How to cite a newspaper article with journal name and date and url for informs journal

Tags: bibtex, urls

I want to cite a newspaper article with the informs journal template.

Based on the guidance example, the reference should consist of: author (year) + title  + journal name (date) + URL. Here is an example:[image]

The bibstyle for my draft is based on informs template at head:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

at end I use

```
\bibliographystyle{informs2014}
\bibliography{msom.bib}
```

First, I tried `@article`, and here is my bib:

```
@article{MIT2013,
author = {Stauffer, N},
title = {Incentives for green technology adoption: Getting 
government subsidies right},
year = {2013},
journal = {Energy Future},
date = {Dec 16},
url = {https://energy.mit.edu/news/incentives-for-green- 
technology-adoption-getting-government-subsidies-right}
}
```

This is my compile result:

[image]

It did not show the date and there is a big width between words

As for using @misc, here is my bib:

```
@misc{MIT2013,
author = {Stauffer, N},
title = {Incentives for green technology adoption: Getting 
government subsidies right},
year = {2013},
journal = {Energy Future},
date = {Dec 16},
howpublished = "\url{https://energy.mit.edu/news/incentives-for- 
green-technology-adoption-getting-government-subsidies-right}"
}
```

The compiled result is:

[image]

It did not show the journal name and date also there is a big gap between words.
So, How can to cite a newspaper article with journal name and date correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Aside: In all bibliography styles I've ever come across (and I've seen quite a few over the years...), `@article` is the only entry type that recognizes and processes the `journal` field (if present, of course). This is due to the fact that the `@article` entry type should be used only for publications in scholarly journals. For sure, one should never use the `@misc` entry type for pieces published in scholarly journals.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, the piece you're looking to cite is neither a newspaper article nor a piece published in a scholarly journal. Instead, it's "just" a piece published on a website. Hence, using the `@article` entry type is inappropriate; moreover, the screenshot template you posted for pieces published in newspapers would appear to be of little relevance for the publication at hand. The month and day-of-month information would also be of little practical relevance for a web-published occasional piece. (Note also that few if any bibtex bibliography styles recognize a field named `date`. The *known* field names are `year` and `month`; however, the `informs2014` bib style doesn't do much (anything??) with the `month` field.)

Oh, and by all means load the `xurl` package, to avoid the "big width between words" issue you've encountered.

Putting all these thoughts together, one gets the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{msom.bib}
@misc{MIT2013,
author       = {Stauffer, Nancy W.},
title        = {Incentives for green technology adoption: 
                Getting government subsidies right},
year         = {2013},
howpublished = {MIT Energy Initiative},
url          = {https://energy.mit.edu/news/incentives-for-green- 
technology-adoption-getting-government-subsidies-right}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{informs2014}
\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\nocite{MIT2013}
\bibliography{msom}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very helpful and forgive my lame English. By the way, can the three capital letters "URL" be cancelled in the reference.

Comment: @Brucexing - The "URL" string is inserted by the `informs2014` bibliography style. Assuming you're using this bibliography style because you've been told to do so, I wouldn't fiddle with any of the `informs2014` settings. If you really want to find out how to suppress this string, please post a new query.